# Distance between two nodes in weighted directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

which algorithm is most optimized for searching the shortest distance between two nodes in positive weighted directed graph?

I know that dijkstra is an option but it calculates from src to all nodes. Same as Floyd-Warshall.

One additional issue. I would need a distance for a node that is source and destination.

For example:

src - F, dest - F
I need it to calculate 2.45 in this example, not 0 as would dijkstra get. Can I modify dijkstra?
I've implemented this one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html

[image: graph]
<sub>(source: [numb3rs at www.math.cornell.edu](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~numb3rs/blanco/net_dif.png))</sub>

Comment: Dijkstra for start -> goal. Floyd-Warshall for any -> any. Also, of course you can have the total weight from Dijkstra algorithm. If that code says 0 when the real weight is 2.45, something is wrong (either the code, your implementation, or your use of it). Dijkstra does *not* calculate from src to all nodes; it calculates only to all nodes that are closer than dest, because it has to.

Comment: But how the solve the issue when start and end node is the same node as described in my question? When you setup dijkstra starting node has to have weight 0 or not?

Comment: Using Floyd-Warshall is an option, just need to declare distance[F][F] = infinity. Or, you can consider creating an F' which is a duplicate of F.

Comment: Force at least one step. Don't check for finality unless you've done at least one recursion. It's the same difference as between `while (x) f();` and `do f(); while (x)`, in languages that support the difference.

Comment: I'll try with the while -> do-while... Pham I've thought about the F' node but didn't successfully done it :-p I would really wanted to do this in Dijkstra. What would be the relation of F' with the rest of the graph?

Comment: Same as to F, without the connection to F itself. Thus, A-F, E-F, F-D, A-F', E-F', F'-D, but no F-F' or F'-F.

Comment: Yes, as @Amadan stated :)

Comment: Pfff I was so close but so far away :) Yesterday I've connected the F'-F and that was my mistake. Can someone post it as an answer? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If A is an algorithm to find shortest path from one vertex to another, and B is an algorithm to find shortest paths between a vertex and all other nodes, it is a proven fact that optimal complexity of A is not better than optimal complexity of B. I.e. you cannot compute path to a single vertex, you have to also compute paths to all other nodes. In simple words, how can you be sure you found the shortest path if you don't even know paths to other nodes?

However, even though there exist no algorithm A with complexity better that algorithm B, a particular implementation of A might be made more optimized than implementation of B, up to a constant factor. In your case of positive edges, you can halt Dijkstra algorithm when the destination vertex is relaxed. But you might still have to process all the vertices in the worst case.

This optimization wouldn't be possible in case you have negative edges, but Dijkstra algorithm cannot handle this case either. You would need [Bellman–Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm for this case.

Floyd-Warshall is overkill here, you obviously don't need paths from all vertices to all others. So Dijkstra is the way to go, I think. If you are looking for the optimal complexity, you can use the heap-based implementation, or even Fibonacci heaps. Complexities for all cases are given in [wiki page for Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). It is also stated that:

> This [Dijkstra with Fibonacci heaps] is asymptotically the fastest known single-source shortest-path
>   algorithm for arbitrary directed graphs with unbounded non-negative
>   weights.

So you shouldn't bother to find any *asymptotically* better algorithm.

Comment: If you want to really squeeze every bit of performance, and know what you're doing, you can of course do everything yourself; but normally you can just use any decent priority queue implementation, as it will be better than what most programmers will write when left to their own devices (Java has `PriorityQueue` in standard library, Ruby has several implementations as gems...). Given a priority queue, Dijkstra algorithm is trivial to code.